# Generation of random sample from a given density function

Tags: probability, statistics, matlab

How to generate random samples associated with a pdf is given by

\begin{equation}
 f_V(v) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{v(2-v)}}
\end{equation}
where $v \in (0,2)$

in MATLAB. As we know in MATLAB 'randn()' is used to generate random numbers which follow a normal distribution and 'rand()' is used to generate random number associated with uniform distribution. But how to generate random samples whose associated pdf is $f_V(v)$.

Comment: First sample $n$ random numbers in $[0,1]$ from a $\mathcal{U}[0,1]$ distribution, then apply $F_{V}^{-1}$ to each of those numbers.

Comment: Otherwise if you have a Beta pseudorandom variate generator nearby, use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate analytically in this case the cdf of your random variable (for lazy people https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt%28x*%282-x%29%29 ). Than:

$$F(x)=1-\frac{2}{\pi} \arcsin \sqrt{1-\frac{x}{2}}$$

for $0\le x\le2$

And $F^{-1}(z)=2-2 \sin^2(\frac{\pi-\pi z}{2})$ (please check my calculations)

So now take $Z\sim U(0,1)$, i.e. use your random uniform enerator. According to theory:

$$G(Z)=2-2 \sin^2\left(\frac{\pi-\pi Z}{2}\right)$$

will be distributed according to the distribution you want. See also here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling

Comment: Thanks your valuable answer

Comment: Note that you will have better performance in inexact arithmetic by using $2\cos^2(\dots)$, particularly when the argument of $\sin$ gets near $\pi/2$.

Comment: @Ian good observation but do you think it can make a different for practical purposes ?

Comment: See my edits to this answer for proper MathJax usage.

Comment: @Thomas This is not about speed, it's about catastrophic cancellation. The speed will improve too, but negligibly so.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks!

Comment: @Ian I never brought up the question of speed :) I am trying to understand your comment. You want to say that when $Z$ gets close to 0 we have 2-2 and therefore issues in the arithmetic right ? But this issue happens only when $Z$ is numerically close to 1 so I would say veeeeeery rarely. This issue should pop up when building billions of samples.

Comment: @Ian in case I am missing something please correct me I am interested in your comment ;)

Comment: It would take a lot of samples to see the error, but probably millions rather than billions. Where it is the clearest is actually where sine is small rather than where it is large: basically anywhere that the sine is less than about $10^{-8}$ in absolute value collapses into one point. Thus the value of $2$ will appear considerably more likely than it should after, say, 10 million samples. There is a similar but milder problem where the sine is close to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
v(2-v) & = {}\overbrace{-(v^2 - 2v) = -(v^2 - 2v+1) + 1}^\text{completing the square} \\[8pt]
& = 1-(v-1)^2
\end{align}

The pdf is for $0<v<2.$ Note that if $v<0$ or $v>2$ then $v(2-v)$ is a negative number under the radical.

\begin{align}
F_V(v) & = \int_0^v \frac{du}{\pi \sqrt{u(2-u)}} \\[8pt] & = \frac 1 \pi \int_0^v \frac{du}{\sqrt{1 - (u-1)^2}} \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 \pi \int_{-1}^{v-1} \frac{dw}{\sqrt{1 - w^2}} \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1 \pi \big( \arcsin(v-1)-\arcsin(-1) \big) \\[8pt]
& = \frac 1 2 + \frac 1 \pi \arcsin(v-1).
\end{align}

$$ \text{So } F_V^{-1}(y) = \sin\left(\pi\left(y - \frac 1 2 \right)\right) + 1 \text{ for } 0\le y\le1.$$

If (capital) $Y$ is a random variable that is uniformly distribution between $0$ and $1,$ then $F_V^{-1}(Y)$ has the distribution that you gave us.